# Why do JDKs come in pairs?

Tags: java

A bit of a silly question, but why do JDK downloads always (?) come with two versions?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Wiki has them often released on the same day as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8_updates

Comment: I'm not seeing the pairing you mention... ?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://superuser.com/questions/1110066/what-is-the-difference-between-java-cpu-and-psu-releases-eg-jdk-se-8u101-and-jd

Comment: @Bobbyrogers yes, thank you. Post it as an answer so I could mark it as such.

Comment: Looks like "always" is too strong. They sometimes come in pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered in superuser:

https://superuser.com/questions/1110066/what-is-the-difference-between-java-cpu-and-psu-releases-eg-jdk-se-8u101-and-jd

TL;DR The latter update (u102) fixes some bugs, but u101 is considered the most recent release.